# Where is the composition root in a WPF MDI application?

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, mdi, composition

In traditional MDI applications some objects (Forms) will be created when a command occurs (Ex. pressing a ribbon button), so it maybe a composition point. I'm confiused about composition root in such applications. I read somewhere that we can use a **ViewModelLocator** which looks like **Service Locator** pattern. As you know the service locator pattern is denounced by some people.

Now please advice me about this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whether or not a ViewModelLocator is a Service Locator or not [depends partly on its signature](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/11/01/PatternRecognitionAbstractFactoryOrServiceLocator.aspx), and [partly on its role](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorRolesVsMechanics.aspx).

In any case, the Composition Root of a WPF application is the [OnStartup method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.onstartup.aspx) - whether or not an application is an MDI application doesn't change that.

Since, in an MDI application, you can have an arbitrary number of child windows, you'll most likely need an Abstract Factory to create each ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks alot mark,
And in general I want my view models to hold a UnitOfWork (UnitOfWork per Form). Should I use method injection for abstract factory methods? In other word, abstract factory methods receive the unitofwork abstraction and something else to find out the proper view model to create. Is it correct?

Comment: And another question is that who should create the Form instances? Can it be the Abstract Factory? I used UserControls as my forms.

Comment: A UoW is basically an Ephemeral Dependency, so that sounds like something best created by an (injected) Abstract Factory.

Comment: Who creates the form instances? Since you are using WPF, I'd suggest applying the MVVM pattern. This means that it's the WPF templating engine that creates the Views based on the type of ViewModel.

Comment: I'm sorry. I have another question! In the Abstract Factory methods I should use "new" keyword or container "resolve" method. It has conflicts with the "Composition Root" concept, doesn't it?

Comment: Not if you put it *in* the Composition Root: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorRolesVsMechanics.aspx

Comment: Mark, you helped me much more than you could think. Thanks a lot. I will try to make a better software.