# How to inject .net core EF into WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-core, .net-standard

I would like to inject my .NET Core EntityFramework `DbContext` (sitting in a .net standard library) into my WPF app.

I tried [this Unity approach](http://www.wpftutorial.net/referencearchitecture.html):

**OnStartup**

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>();
var mainWindow = container.Resolve<MainWindow>();

base.OnStartup(e);
```

**MainWindow**

```
private ApplicationDbContext _db;
[Dependency]
public ApplicationDbContext Db
{
    get
    {
        return _db;
    }
    set
    {
        _db = value;
    }
}

public MainWindow()
{
    //StandardDatabase.Commands.Test();

    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    FrameContent.Navigate(new PageConsignments());
}
```

But I get this error at `container.Resolve<MainWindow>()`:

> The current type, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2[System.Type,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IDbContextOptionsExtension], is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Does anyone know if I'm doing something wrong? Any suggestions on a better way of doing this are welcome

**ApplicationDbContext**

```
public ApplicationDbContext() : base() { }

public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
{ }

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
        .UseSqlServer("Server=L-TO-THE-APTOP\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Maloli;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");

    optionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(x => x.Ignore(CoreEventId.LazyLoadOnDisposedContextWarning));
}
```

As per Nkosi's suggestion, I removed the `ApplicationDbContext(options)` ctor from the context, and that got rid of the error.However I am now checking the value of `Db` here in `MainWindow`:

```
private ICommand goPack;
public ICommand GoPack
{
    get
    {
        return goPack
            ?? (goPack = new ActionCommand(() =>
            {
                var c = _db.Parts;
                FrameContent.Navigate(new PageConsignments());
            }));
    }
}
```

But it returns `null`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the composition root in a WPF MDI application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079530/where-is-the-composition-root-in-a-wpf-mdi-application)

Comment: Did you properly configure the `ApplicationDbContext` with the container. It would appear you did not setup the context builder options for the DbContext

Comment: Remove the constructor with the options

Comment: @Nkosi That seems to have got rid of the error! However, in `MainWindow` I can see that `Db` is `null`

Comment: @Bassie that depends on when you are checking its value. If you check it before the container has had a chance to inject the dependency, like having a breakpoint in the constructor, it will definitely be null at that point in the initialization process

Comment: @Nkosi I'm checking the value in an `ICommand` after the ctor is called (I updated the question) a

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that there is not support for .Net Core for WPF (and Winforms).

Comment: @Bassie for troubleshooting, try to resolve the DbContext immediately after registering it to see if it will resolve successfully. If it does then you need to take into consideration when the MainWindow gets the property set when compared to the dependent properties using the value.

Comment: Also, ideally, that context should really be explicitly injected into a view model and not directly on the View.

Comment: @Nkosi `container.Resolve<ApplicationDbContext>` works just after calling `RegisterType`.

Comment: Ok hold on, drafting up something based on the same tutorial you linked to

Comment: @Luis .NET Core will support WPF applications in .NET Core 3.0. Not out yet.

Comment: @Adam yes, in the future, but not today :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original error was because the container was selecting the constructor that expected `DbContextOptionsBuilder` which the conateinr did not know how to resolve properly.

Since the context is being configured within the `OnConfiguring` override then there is no need for

```
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
{ }
```

Remove that constructor so the container resolve the context without errors.

Depending on the flow of dependency initialization and access to it, that context should really be explicitly injected into a view model and not directly on the View.

Following MVVM, have all the necessary dependencies and bindable properties in the view model

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel {
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext db;

    public MainWindowViewModel(ApplicationDbContext db) {
        this.db = db;            
    }

    private ICommand goPack;
    public ICommand GoPack {
        get {
            return goPack
                ?? (goPack = new ActionCommand(() =>
                {
                    var c = db.Parts;
                    FrameContent.Navigate(new PageConsignments());
                }));
        }
    }
}
```

Update the View to depend on the view model

```
public class MainWindow : Window {
    [Dependency]
    public MainWindowViewModel ViewModel {
        set { DataContext = value; }
    }

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    void OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args) {
        FrameContent.Navigate(new PageConsignments());
    }
}
```

All that is left now is to make sure all dependencies are registered with container

```
public class App : Application {
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) {
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>();
        container.RegisterType<MainWindowViewModel>();
        container.RegisterType<MainWindow>();

        MainWindow mainWindow = container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

Where ever possible, [The Explicit Dependencies Principle](https://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/) via constructor injection should be preferred over property injection.

But since most views do not lend well to constructor injection the latter is usually applied. By making sure the view model has all the necessary dependencies before injecting it into the view you ensure that all required values are available when needed.

Comment: This works for `MainWindow` but when trying to display other pages in that window they don't have the requied dependencies

Comment: That is just a matter of design choices. You can just as easily inject the necessary pages and pass them forward.

Comment: @Nkosi With this approach, do I need to explicitly `Dispose` the `DbContext`?